# Python not working on a bash script but working on the terminal. How to solve it?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-23.10

I am trying to run a **Python** program through a **Bash** script. When I execute the python file by shell it works with no problem, but when I try to execute the script, the `python` keyword is not recognized.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 23.10 installation and I added, on top of the `~/.bashrc` file, the following line:

```
alias python=python3
```

How to solve this problem?

#### Toy example

For sake of simplicity I made a toy example that displays the same behavior.

I have an `hello-world.py` file, whose content is simply

```
print("Hello World!")
```

If I run it with the shell (`$ python hello-world.py`), it works smoothly:

> Hello World!

Now I created a script `start.sh` whose content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

python hello-world.py
```

But if I execute it `$ ./start.sh` I get the following error:

> ./start.sh: line 3: python: command not found

Comment: `python` is undefined in new Ubuntu versions since `python2` was stopped. Refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296887) for a more detailed description. You should probably replace `python` with `python3` in your script if it is possible. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/a/98786) about the alias not working

Comment: You are trying to run bash-aliases from a script, but you neither sourced your .bashrc, nor  did not on alias expansion (`shopt -s expand_aliases`). So your aliases are not defined, and even if they were defined, they would not be expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the issue is that your shebang isn't running bash as a login shell (which is pretty normal). You are aliasing `python` to `python3` in your `.bashrc`, but that will only get run in a login shell. So try adding:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

to your shebang.

Although, to be clear, I would consider this a hack. I would suggest that ideally you just use `python3` in the shell script.

Or, create a symlink. If you are on ubuntu, you can use `python-is-python3`:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python3

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think it's a good practice using `python3` instead of `python`?  Also what is the difference between using `python-is-python3` and `ln -s`?

Comment: Hi, .bashrc is not used in login shell (unless you source it like from .bash_profile , many distributions do). Overall, running login shell may have unintended consequences and results in slower startup.

Comment: On Debian, yes it's what you are meant to do. `python-is-python3` is just providing unified way to do this. You can do it manually.

Comment: @KamilCuk ah, that is the case in Ubuntu, I believe?

Answer (score 2):

.bashrc is not sourced when running noninteractive shell.

Aliases are disabled in noninteractive shell (by default).

A script is noninteractive, so these settings are ignored.

Refer to bash [documentation on startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

> how to solve it?

Create a symlink in a directory added to PATH with the name python that links to python3 executable.  For example `/usr/local/bin` or `~/.local/bin`.

Use your linux distribution specific settings, like `apt-get install python-is-python3`.

Either way, use `python3` in your scripts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically at least five kinds of Bash shell invocations:

1. interactive + login
2. interactive + non-login
3. non-interactive + --login option
4. non-interactive + remote-login (via rshd or sshd)
5. non-interactive + non-login

The descriptions are taken from the [Bash Manual, 6.2. Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

1+3 )

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
> non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
> executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
> After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
> and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
> the first one that exists and is readable.

2 )

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
> reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

4 )

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard
> input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the
> historical remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell
> daemon sshd. If Bash determines it is being run non-interactively in
> this fashion, it reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that
> file exists and is readable. It will not do this if invoked as sh

5 )

> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
> example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
> expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
> the name of a file to read and execute

I've descibed a way to handle all five invocations with minimum effort startup files. Please find the details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758273/how-to-export-global-variables-to-child-process-in-bash/765305#answer-765305).

Basically you create three small Bash startup files in your HOME directory:

```
~/.bash_env:

[ -n "$BASH_ENV_VERSION" ] && return 0
BASH_ENV_VERSION=.....
...
[ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ] && source "$HOME/.bash_aliases"
...

~/.bashrc:    

if [ -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" ]; then
    [ -z "$BASH_ENV" ] && export BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bash_env"
    source "$BASH_ENV"  
fi

~/.bash_profile:

 [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && source "$HOME/.profile"
 [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

The `~/.bash_env` is where all your variables and functions go which you like to have at hand no matter how bash has been invoked. The first two lines are a guard against multiple inclusions. No shebangs needed!

Finally, put your Bash alias definitions in the file `~/.bash_aliases`

This can be extended to cover startup files for other login shells and Bash invocations in POSIX mode, e.g. when started as `sh` or with the `--posix` command line option. In that case you may want to use the `ENV` variable instead of `BASH_ENV` and define it in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`. I intentionally left that out to not make things too complicated.